# Why isn't the broadcast receiver working? I have tried quite a few solutions posted in this site as well in others however it isn't working. Help me

Tags: java, android, xml, broadcastreceiver

This is my code in the Broadcast receiver class

```
package com.example.manjit.myapplication;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "working!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

And the manifest file contains the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.manjit.myapplication">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <receiver
            android:name=".MyReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I have tried the code with many actions such as `action android:name="android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG"` but the toast is not displayed. Please help me out. I have tried running on Lolipop

Comment: What isn't working?

Comment: In which OS you tried this?

Comment: I have tried it on Android 5.1.1..No toast is displayed

Comment: You'll need to add an `Activity` to your app that you run at least once after installation to bring your app out of the _stopped_ state. Your Receiver won't work until then. Also, you cannot receive the `HEADSET_PLUG` broadcast in a manifest-registered Receiver.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add both actions:

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And change your receiver like this:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction() == Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (intent.getAction() == Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot register receivers in the manifest for most implicit broadcasts on Android 8 and newer [due to background execution limitations](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#broadcasts).